# Ion auth only show users in certain group

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have installed a user management with Ion auth in codeigniter. Now i'm facing the following challenge.

When logged in and visiting the auto/index page an overview of users is shown. I'm using 3 different admin levels. Each user is connected to a company. (the company id is added in the users_groups table)

Admin
company-admin
company-user

The super admin should see all the users,
The Admin should only see the users which are also in the same company
The user has got no access to the auth/index (that already works)

How can I create a page in such a way that a Admin only sees his company users. Below an examaple of the index function of my auth.php controller.

```
//redirect if needed, otherwise display the user list
function index()
{

    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        //redirect them to the login page
        redirect('dashboard/', 'refresh');
    }
    elseif ($this->ion_auth->in_group('company-user')) 
    {
        //redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
        redirect('dashboard/', 'refresh');


        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        //list the users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();              
        }           
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->companies = $this->ion_auth->get_company($user->id)->result();        
        }           


    }
    elseif ($this->ion_auth->logged_in() && $this->ion_auth->in_group("company-admin"))
    {
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        //list the users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
        }
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->companies = $this->ion_auth->get_company($user->id)->result();
        }


        $this->_render_page('admin/auth/index', $this->data);
    }       
    else
    {
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        //list the users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result();
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
        }
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->companies = $this->ion_auth->get_company($user->id)->result();
        }

        $this->_render_page('admin/auth/index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what i've got to add to the elseif ($this->ion_auth->in_group("company-admin")) part in order to only show the users in the same company as the company-admin?

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks for the answer. Now i've made the following changes:

I'm answering this way, to have the possibility to show code. I have changed my controller but still see users from other companies. I have changed this as following:

```
elseif ($this->ion_auth->in_group("company-admin"))
    {
        //set the flash data error message if there is one
        $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors()) ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message');

        // Check the company the user is in
        $user_in_company = $this->ion_auth->get_users_companies(); // Return array groups

        //list the users
        $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users()->result($user_in_company);
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->groups = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups($user->id)->result();
        }
        foreach ($this->data['users'] as $k => $user)
        {
            $this->data['users'][$k]->companies = $this->ion_auth->get_company($user->id)->result();
        }

        $this->_render_page('admin/auth/index', $this->data);
    }
```

I would expect to view only the users within the company thoug.. wat could be wrong with my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first get groups logged user.

```
$user_in_group = $this->ion_auth->get_users_groups(); // Return array groups
```

And get user list that have same group with logged user

```
$this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users($user_in_group)->result(); // Pass groups array as params
```

And users listed only have logged user group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have changed my code (see above for the changes) I was expecting my auth/index to show only the users within the company, but I still see all the users.

Comment: @mastahb `in_group` is only check user in group or not. With my codes, only list users passed group. And i updated codes about line `$this->data['users']`. Check out.

Comment: I have solved this problem by creating a new function within my ion_auth_model to fetch the correct data from the DB

Comment: jep I tried but didn't get them to work. I'm pretty new to this so still experimenting.. but thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this

`$group_id = 3; //your group id in database
 $this->data['users'] = $this->ion_auth->users($group_id)->result();`

then loop in your view.